# Filter tasks doesn't work - Todo list with MVC pattern using es6 classes

Tags: javascript, object, model-view-controller, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to write a todo list project with pure JS using MVC pattern. It's my first project with MVC and I have a real problem that I can't solve.
I have three buttons, each button gets a value as filter value (in Model class) for **complete**, **active** and **all** task. default value for filter is **0** that refers to **all** button.
when complete button is active, new todo adds to page, but that page is only for complete todo and new todo must add to all pages while complete page is still active.
I write some methods for handle it, but they doesn't work and I can't understand where is the problem.
how can I solve it?

this is my code:

```js
class Model {
    constructor() {
        this.todoS = [];
        this.filter = 0;
    }

    bindTodoListChanged(callback) {
        this.onTodoListChanged = callback;
    }

    _commit(todoS) {
        this.onTodoListChanged(todoS);
    }

    addTodo(todoText) {
        var todo = {
            id:
                this.todoS.length > 0
                    ? this.todoS[this.todoS.length - 1].id + 1
                    : 0,
            text: todoText,
            complete: false
        };

        this.todoS.push(todo);

        this._commit(this.todoS);
    }

    toggleTodo(id) {
        this.todoS = this.todoS.map(todo =>
            todo.id === id
                ? {
                      id: todo.id,
                      text: todo.text,
                      complete: !todo.complete
                  }
                : todo
        );

        this._commit(this.todoS);
    }

    filterTodo(filter) {
        this.todoS.filter(todo => {
            if (filter === 0) return true;
            return filter === 1 ? !todo.complete : todo.complete;
        });
    }
}

class View {
    constructor() {
        this.form = document.querySelector("#taskForm");
        this.input = document.getElementById("taskInput");
        this.list = document.querySelector("#taskList");
        this.filterBtnS = document.getElementById("filterButtons");
        this.allBtn = document.querySelector(".all");
        this.activeBtn = document.querySelector(".active");
        this.completeBtn = document.querySelector(".complete");
    }

    createElement(tag, className) {
        var element = document.createElement(tag);
        if (className) element.classList.add(className);

        return element;
    }

    getElement(selector) {
        var element = document.querySelector(selector);

        return element;
    }

    get _todoText() {
        return this.input.value;
    }

    _resetInput() {
        this.input.value = "";
    }

    displayTodoS(todoS) {
        // Faster way for clear tasks
        while (this.list.firstChild) {
            this.list.removeChild(this.list.firstChild);
        }

        if (todoS.length !== 0) {
            todoS.forEach(todo => {
                var li = this.createElement("li", "task"),
                    span = this.createElement("span");

                li.id = todo.id;            

                var checkbox = this.createElement("input");
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.checked = todo.complete;

                if (todo.complete) {
                    var strike = this.createElement("s");
                    strike.textContent = todo.text;
                    span.innerHTML = "";    
                    span.append(strike);
                } else {
                    span.textContent = todo.text;
                }

                li.append(checkbox, span);

                this.list.append(li);
            });
        }
    }

    bindAddTodo(handler) {
        this.form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (this._todoText) {
                handler(this._todoText);
                this._resetInput();
            } 
        });
    }
    
    bindToggleTodo(handler) {
        this.list.addEventListener("change", event => {
            if (event.target.type === "checkbox") {
                var id = +event.target.parentElement.id;

                handler(id);
            }
        });
    }

    bindFilterTodo(handler) {
        this.filterBtnS.addEventListener("click", e => {
            var filter = +e.target.getAttribute("value");

            handler(filter);
        });
    }

}

class Controller {
    constructor(model, view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        this.model.bindTodoListChanged(this.onTodoListChanged);
        this.view.bindAddTodo(this.handleAddTodo);
        this.view.bindToggleTodo(this.handleToggleTodo);
        this.view.bindFilterTodo(this.handleFilterTodo);

        this.onTodoListChanged(this.model.todoS);
    }

    onTodoListChanged = todoS => {
        this.view.displayTodoS(todoS);
    };

    handleAddTodo = todoText => {
        this.model.addTodo(todoText);
    };

    handleToggleTodo = id => {
        this.model.toggleTodo(id);
    };

    handleFilterTodo = filter => {
        this.model.filterTodo(filter);
    };
}

var app = new Controller(new Model(), new View());
```

```html
<div id="main">
            <h2>Task List</h2>
            <form id="taskForm">
                <input
                    id="taskInput"
                    placeholder="New task..."
                    autocomplete="off"
                />
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add Task" />
            </form>
            <div id="filterButtons" class="buttons">
                <div class="all" value="0">All</div>
                <div class="active" value="1">Active</div>
                <div class="complete" value="2">Completed</div>
            </div>
            <ul id="taskList"></ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. Can you describe steps, what you expect to happened and what's actually happening? Also, seems that `activeBtn` and `completeBtn` only been declared but never bound to `click` events..

Comment: @MoshFeu I expect to happened something like that: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html . for 3 buttons bounded to ```click``` event here: bindFilterTodo(handler) { this.filterBtnS.addEventListener("click", e => { var filter = +e.target.getAttribute("value"); handler(filter); }); }

Comment: Right. Didn't notice this. I've added my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in `filterTodo`, you just filter the tasks but not `_commit` the change.

So

1. Store the filter in the model
2. Move the filter to `_commit` (so it will keep filter for any other actions such as add todo)

```js
class Model {
    constructor() {
        this.todoS = [];
        this.filter = 0;
    }

    bindTodoListChanged(callback) {
        this.onTodoListChanged = callback;
    }

    _commit(todoS = this.todoS) {
        this.onTodoListChanged(todoS.filter(todo => {
            if (this.filter === 0) return true;
            return this.filter === 1 ? !todo.complete : todo.complete;
        }));
    }

    addTodo(todoText) {
        var todo = {
            id:
                this.todoS.length > 0
                    ? this.todoS[this.todoS.length - 1].id + 1
                    : 0,
            text: todoText,
            complete: false
        };

        this.todoS.push(todo);

        this._commit(this.todoS);
    }

    toggleTodo(id) {
        this.todoS = this.todoS.map(todo =>
            todo.id === id
                ? {
                      id: todo.id,
                      text: todo.text,
                      complete: !todo.complete
                  }
                : todo
        );

        this._commit(this.todoS);
    }

    filterTodo(filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
        this._commit();
    }
}

class View {
    constructor() {
        this.form = document.querySelector("#taskForm");
        this.input = document.getElementById("taskInput");
        this.list = document.querySelector("#taskList");
        this.filterBtnS = document.getElementById("filterButtons");
        this.allBtn = document.querySelector(".all");
        this.activeBtn = document.querySelector(".active");
        this.completeBtn = document.querySelector(".complete");
    }

    createElement(tag, className) {
        var element = document.createElement(tag);
        if (className) element.classList.add(className);

        return element;
    }

    getElement(selector) {
        var element = document.querySelector(selector);

        return element;
    }

    get _todoText() {
        return this.input.value;
    }

    _resetInput() {
        this.input.value = "";
    }

    displayTodoS(todoS) {
        // Faster way for clear tasks
        while (this.list.firstChild) {
            this.list.removeChild(this.list.firstChild);
        }

        if (todoS.length !== 0) {
            todoS.forEach(todo => {
                var li = this.createElement("li", "task"),
                    span = this.createElement("span");

                li.id = todo.id;            

                var checkbox = this.createElement("input");
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.checked = todo.complete;

                if (todo.complete) {
                    var strike = this.createElement("s");
                    strike.textContent = todo.text;
                    span.innerHTML = "";    
                    span.append(strike);
                } else {
                    span.textContent = todo.text;
                }

                li.append(checkbox, span);

                this.list.append(li);
            });
        }
    }

    bindAddTodo(handler) {
        this.form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (this._todoText) {
                handler(this._todoText);
                this._resetInput();
            } 
        });
    }
    
    bindToggleTodo(handler) {
        this.list.addEventListener("change", event => {
            if (event.target.type === "checkbox") {
                var id = +event.target.parentElement.id;

                handler(id);
            }
        });
    }

    bindFilterTodo(handler) {
        this.filterBtnS.addEventListener("click", e => {
            var filter = +e.target.getAttribute("value");

            handler(filter);
        });
    }

}

class Controller {
    constructor(model, view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        this.model.bindTodoListChanged(this.onTodoListChanged);
        this.view.bindAddTodo(this.handleAddTodo);
        this.view.bindToggleTodo(this.handleToggleTodo);
        this.view.bindFilterTodo(this.handleFilterTodo);

        this.onTodoListChanged(this.model.todoS);
    }

    onTodoListChanged = todoS => {
        console.log(todoS);
        this.view.displayTodoS(todoS);
    };

    handleAddTodo = todoText => {
        this.model.addTodo(todoText);
    };

    handleToggleTodo = id => {
        this.model.toggleTodo(id);
    };

    handleFilterTodo = filter => {
        this.model.filterTodo(filter);
    };
}

var app = new Controller(new Model(), new View());
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h2>Task List</h2>
  <form id="taskForm">
    <input id="taskInput" placeholder="New task..." autocomplete="off" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add Task" />
  </form>
  <div id="filterButtons" class="buttons">
    <div class="all" value="0">All</div>
    <div class="active" value="1">Active</div>
    <div class="complete" value="2">Completed</div>
  </div>
  <ul id="taskList"></ul>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1u6dxi

Comment: Thank you for your time.
But that's not my answer. When you add a new todo to the list, you exit the active button and redirect to the homepage.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by `redirect to the homepage`. Here is how it works for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKoGt.gif

Comment: Happy to hear :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the biggest issues in the returning of values. For example this:

```
handleFilterTodo = filter => {
    this.model.filterTodo(filter);
};
```

This code does not return anything, it only calls `this.model.filterTodo`. In the corresponding method `filterTodo`, you are creating a new array by using `this.todoS.filter` but you do not return it anywhere:

```
filterTodo(filter) {
    this.todoS.filter(todo => {
        if (filter === 0) return true;
        return filter === 1 ? !todo.complete : todo.complete;
    });
}
```

You could do something like what you did with `toggleTodo` and the `map` function here:

```
filterTodo(filter) {
    this.todoS = this.todoS.filter(todo => {
        if (filter === 0) return true;
        return filter === 1 ? !todo.complete : todo.complete;
    });
}
```

...but that would only work once, as setting the filter would remove the other todos from your database.

From my understanding of the code (without trying it out), I'd probably set the filter only and whenever `_commit` gets called, pass the filtered version of the todos based on the selected filter

```
constructor() {
    ...
    this.possibleFilters = {
        0: () => true,
        1: todo => !todo.completed,
        2: todo => todo.completed
    };
}

filterTodo(filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
}

_commit(todoS) {
    const selectedFilter = this.possibleFilters[this.filter];
    this.onTodoListChanged(todoS.filter(selectedFilter));
}
```

Comment: where the ```currentFilter``` defined?

Comment: Sorry, it's `this.filter` (what's getting saved in `filterTodo`)